# How to return a value from a job?

Tags: bash, shell-script, job-control, subshell, jobs

I want to spin up some jobs within a script to do some work in parallel. I will know when the work is done by counting the number of active jobs. The issue I'm having is that I want to also return a value from these jobs without having to deal with writing to and reading from a temporary while.

In this example you will see that I can count the number of running jobs but the value of `a` is not updated to `456`:

```
function _n_jobs() {
   echo $(jobs -r | wc -l | tr -d " ")
}

a=123

(
   sleep 2s
   a=456
) &

echo "Number of jobs: "$(_n_jobs)

while (( $(_n_jobs) > 0 )); do
   sleep 0.1s
done

echo $a
```

I found that I can write the output of a subshell to a file descriptor to get a value from a task run in parallel. But this is subshell is not registered as a job. This means that I can't know when a series of parallel tasks have finished because I can't count them as I could with jobs.

In this example I can get a value from the subshell by redirecting its output to a file descriptor but the number of jobs is `0`.

```
function _n_jobs() {
   echo $(jobs -r | wc -l | tr -d " ")
}

a=123

exec {fd}< <(
   sleep 2s
   echo 456
)

echo "Number of jobs: "$(_n_jobs)

read <&${fd} a

echo $a
```

Is there a way that I can return a value from a job in this way?

Even though my examples are returning numbers, reading the exit code is not sufficient. I would like for the result to be arbitrary such that I can return a string as well, which is why I am using file descriptors.

Comment: `read` will block until it has anything to read.

Comment: Also, use `wait` rather then counting the jobs yourself.

Comment: These is just example code meant to illustrate the question.

Comment: Have you considered named pipes?